# Pattern no funciona HTML

Tags: html, formularios, regex

El caso es que estoy haciendo un simple formulario y quiero meter pattern para evitar que me pongan números en el nombre y lo ignora totalmente. Sea cual sea el pattern que le ponga, solo números, solo letras, sea lo que sea ignora totalmente el pattern y cuando se escribe algo en el formulario sea un carácter o un símbolo o letra o número se envía.

```html
<form class="modal-form">
      <p> <span >Indicanos tus datos y cuéntanos sobre qué tienes dudas</span > </p>
  
      <div class="input">
        <input id="name-cont" name="name-cont" type="text" patern='[a-zA-z]' required maxlength="60"  onfocusout="hasValue('name-cont')"/>
        <label id="tag-name-cont" for="name-cont">Nombre</label>
      </div>
    
      <button class="button-blue">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Parece que has escrito mal pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente te quieres referir a a-zA-Z, no a-zA-z como has puesto. Esos errores son muy comunes.

Comment: Si añades a la respuesta lo que ha comentado r4ziel de patern en vez de pattern, aclaras un poco lo de a-zA-Z y le metes un link a la documentación de pattern te quedaría una respuesta de 10 :-)